# A candle inside a jar situation

Tags: thermodynamics

A question, we know  that a candle goes out inside a closed jar, but why?, What if I keep a candle inside a jar with top part open?
What will happen if make the jar very long but top open?, 
Now, another situation What if I kept two candles of different height and light them up inside a closed jar, which one will go out first?

Comment: Do you think you could respond or accept? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would depend on how long the jar is. If the heat generated by the candle is not enough for ventilation to occur, the candle would simply burn out. It might last a few moments, but as the carbon dioxide is recycled, the flame would get smaller and smaller until it died.

If the jar was short enough that the carbon dioxide made in the chemical reaction makes it out the top of the jar allowing fresh air to be vented in, the candle will burn.

For the last case I think every combination of candle states is possible depending on the differences in distances.

A candle goes out when in a closed jar because it cannot vent the carbon dioxide made in the chemical reaction. Carbon dioxide will not burn and suffocates the candle when oxygen is depleted.